# Spanning Subspaces in Finite Field Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q^m$ be vector space over $\mathbb{F}_q$. For a $k\geq m$ a set $A$ of vectors is called ``almost spanning'' if every subset $B\subseteq A$ with $|B|=k$ span the entire vector space, i.e.,

$$\text{span}(B) = \mathbb{F}_q^m.$$
What is the maximum size of $A$?

Comment: Should the adverb *almost* be used to modify another word in this definition?

Comment: This is a nice problem.  What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: When $m=2$ the answer is $q+1$. This is because the set $A$ consisting of $(0,1)$ and $(1,x_i)$, $i=1,2,\ldots,q,$ with $\Bbb{F}_q=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_q\}$ has this property, and every non-zero vector is a scalar multiple of exactly one of the vectors in $A$. The answer is probably known in coding theory, but I haven't had my morning coffee, and cannot think straight.

Comment: But do read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound#MDS_codes) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(projective_geometry)).

Comment: @hardmath: You are right. I fixed it.